# mapping for question mark for backwards search

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I have created a map in my .vimrc file for the backwards search (?)

```
map <c-space> ?
```

but it doesn't perform the search when typing ctrl+space. I am using 
Vim 7.3.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use that combination. May I ask why you would want to use it instead of the more simple and standard question mark?

Comment: You can't map `<C-Space>` in terminal Vim, just like you can't map `<M-` and `<S-` combos. Try a GUI Vim instead: on my MacVim it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.